# Standard Java Error Reporting

Tags: java

I am currently working on creating a toolkit for work and I've gotten to the point where I'm wondering about error reporting.

Basically all of my tools, which consist of a grouping of classes, will eventually be ran from a main method.  Many of these tools will be doing operations on file like reading them in and converting them into some sort of array of objects or writing an object array to a file in a certain format. Whenever you are dealing with data that your program didn't create there is always room for error and those errors need to be known.

With that said what would be a good method to document all of the errors that occur during the processing and allow them to be retrieved later?  Considering that I may want to send these error information out later I don't think that Log4J would be a good fit.  I was considering using a string builder in each of my processing classes and append all error to that builder and retrieve it later at my leisure.  I was also thinking of using some sort of arrayList or something that would hold the different types of errors but I'm a bit at a loss.

Does anyone have any good methods of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to enable remote logging.  Log4J is a fine fit for this.  What you can do in the most basic way possible is open up a socket that sends data to a message queue.  This message queue will have a listener attached to it that can handle the different log messages it receives.  This data can later be persisted into a database which you can than query against to generate reports.

Using StringBuilder makes very little to no sense, because it sounds like you are trying to just consume a bunch of space on the host system.

**FROM THE COMMENTS**

> Correct, once these errors are fixed I no longer need them. Is it
>   standard practice to funnel all errors from applications into a single
>   database? I don't mind keeping the data if this is the correct method
>   of doing so however only the newest information will be looked at

It is more a standard practice to keep a dedicated audit log, depending on your policy / legal requirements this can be anywhere from 90 days to 2 years.  This enables you to go back and prove that steps were taken to mitigate compliance issues, track down malicious activity, etc.  While it is true that logs are only good for a limited period of time, it is greatly beneficial to see audit logs when you are trying to track down a recurring issue in the system.

Comment: Considering that the error data is only useful until the next run would it still be wise to store it in a database?  I could remove the old data but that seems like extra work.

Comment: @DavidWallace so you want to completely lose an audit trail?

Comment: Correct, once these errors are fixed I no longer need them.  Is it standard practice to funnel all errors from applications into a single database?  I don't mind keeping the data if this is the correct method of doing so however only the newest information will be looked at.

Comment: @DavidWallace edited my answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace `cat ~/Library/Logs/** /var/log/** /Library/Logs/** | xz | wc -c` tells me *all the logs* produced on my system since whenever I bothered to nuke them compress down into 5MB. The user can live with whatever you produce. And standard practice is to funnel them into logs and inspect those whenever necessary, but if you're trying to roll your own integrated error reporting solution you're obviously not in a standard situation.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Thank you for your help.  It appears my question isn't up to par for SO but I got what I needed and will work on an implementation.